# Motion tracking slipping and MANY MORE ISSUES

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

I have been trying to learn motion tracking for 5 days and all the results I get are inconsistent. It's either I go through the solve error starts really low, I decrease maybe a trackers weight solve again, and boom its to like above 100 for some reason. and the orientation I'm not sure if it's my issue or not but I've tried to get it as close as possible and once I press play the object keeps sliding and moving. I've tried with different footage and different scenes. now I decide ill do a simple track with paper and markers and I cant also get that to work properly without the solve breaking randomly or if I do manage to get the solve low under 1px but then the object won't stop sliding and shifting. I'm not sure if its an issue with my footage or blender hates me. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be a lenses issue, of course, try enabling refining optical center and distortion coefficient. Also try entering your keyframes, instead of suggested ones, for keyframes choose two frames with maximum shift of the camera.

[image]

Comment: I've played with the lens a lot, I'm using an iPhone XS max, I've googled I used the info I found, and the refine focal length always gave me a better solution... even though the focal length I got was nowhere near the iPhone camera specs. but ill try more tweaking

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 3D camera and objects are correctly scaled to real world units and the distance between your camera and 3D objects is relatively similar to the real world that can get rid of the sliding and moving and provide proper parallax relative to your footage.

---

I assume you correctly matched your sensor size other than that i can only suggest tweaking your keyframes to get a better solve. essentially pick a range of 30 or so frames where the markers are dead on perfectly tracked and see what kind of solve error you get
*generally 1px or less will work and 0.5px or less will get a very good track*

---

A **crucial** step is to set your floor using 3 trackers. then line up the X or Y axis with something like the edge of that table in the camera view.

Comment: the first solution I got was 0.5px got greedy and decided to tweak the weight of literally one tracker and the solution jumped to 3px, camera sensor I keep playing around with it because it's so inconsistent, I try to eyeball the scale the 3d camera and objects when I see that it looks fine and makes sense, I press play and the cube won't stop sliding. i don't know if there is a better method for getting the scale as accurate as possible